# Express wont find css file

Tags: javascript, html, express

I cant get my index.html in express to show the styles.

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

And then on server js I have this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(useragent.express());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
  let isMobile = req.useragent.isMobile ? 'mobile' : 'desktop';
  console.log({isMobile})
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + `/${isMobile}/index.html`));
});
```

And I just add the link tag on my html inside the head on the index.html like this:

```
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The index I serve can be either inside the desktop or mobile folder
But it doesnt get the styles... any idea whats the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Open the developer tools in  your browser. Look at the network tab. Is a request for the stylesheet being made? Is it to the URL you expect? Does it have a 200 OK response code? Does the response body contain the CSS you expect? If you paste that CSS into https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ does it validate? What changes to the HTML do you expect? Do the selectors actually match the structure of your document?

Comment: Ah its in the tab.. found the error... i had className instead of class bc it was ported from jsx... oops.. thx :)

Comment: You should delete the question if the problem turned out to be a typo. Don’t mark a completely wrong answer as solving your problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

server.js

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public')
```

index.html

```html
<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: nah... still doesnt work.

Comment: @GiorgioMartini Try

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public')